# How feasible is it to build a benchtop semiconductor protoyping fabrication set up?

Tags: electrical-engineering, semiconductor

This is generally quite a vague question as I'm new to the space but I've been thinking a lot about 1 off prototyping in the IC/semiconductor space and have been wondering about the feasibility of developing a small scale/benchtop system that is capable of making chip prototypes.

Can anyone who knows more about this fill in the gaps here and tell me where I'm likely wrong? Why or why not would a system like this work?

Comment: Feasible? Yes, if you have the tools and skills. Probably better asked on Electrical / Electronics but improve the question and read their FAQ's first.

Comment: Wouldn't the chemicals required be toxic and expensive, not to mention the equipment?

Comment: Many universities or other labs have 'bench top' capability, often using old (1980's or earlier) equipment that could actually fit on a bench top. But, you won't be prototyping 5 nanometer CMOS transistors, more like 5 micron devices.

Answer (score 3):

This question about garage microelectronics is asked quite frequently.
Normal microelectronics is not just photolithography as some people think and cannot fit onto desktop, not many universities in the world have full-cycle of it (my has). What you will need (roughly):

- Electronic grade Si wafers (easy to get in areas close to microelectronics, example with prices: https://order.universitywafer.com/default.aspx?cat=Silicon)
- Extra purity acetone, alcohol, water, sulfuric acid, ammonia, hydrofluoric acid, PTFE dishes for it and good fume hood for it. These are for cleaning.
- Clean room without dust, with HEPA filters on air income, all equipment clean.
- High purity argon, nitrogen for many processes.
- Dopant deposition setup. Usually they are deposited from gas phase and some of these gases are chemical warfare agents (very dangerous, costly and much of paperwork). Setup contains mid-vacuum system (quite costly), MFC, thermostats etc.
- Dopant diffusion furnace. Simplest is quartz-pipe open end furnace with controlled temp. profile up to 1200°C and inert media.
- Oxide growth furnace. Nearly same, but separate to avoid impurities. Oxygen and water vapour addition capability for thick oxide growth.
- Gas-phase epitaxial setup if you wish to fabricate devices newer than 50 years old. Looks close to previous, but more advanced control and purity. Requires precision flows of gases-carriers of silicon and its dopants (costly and very dangerous)
- Gas-phase silicon oxide deposition setup, for inter-layer isolation and passivation. Contains vacuum system and plasma source. Requires silane.
- Oxygen plasma setup for cleaning substrates and photoresist removal and after-development treatment. Contains vacuum system and plasma source.
- Etching setup. Can be combined with previous. Requires fluorine-containing gas, dangerous.
- Metal deposition setup, usually aluminium. May be DC magnetron based (mid-vacuum) or thermal evaporation (requires high vacuum).
- Centrifuge for photoresist coating. And actually photoresist.
- Hot plate with at least 2°C accuracy for photoresist drying and hardening.
- Photolithography setup. Typical old contact lithography gives down to 2 micron resolution. Actually, this is may be the simplest and cheapest setup of all above.
- Mask production setup for lithography. In general, this is CNC laser plotter with 1-2 micron precision. It can replace contact lithography setup if mass production is not required.
- Silicon wafer cutting machine (diamond disk). Can be replaced by sapphire or diamond needle in skillful hands.
- Ultrasound or thermocompression microwire-welding setup for crystal packaging.
- much very expensive test and characterization equipment to measure properties of coatings, structures and finally, devices and circuits which you will create with equipment above.

And finally, all of this will be nearly useless for practical purpose because integrated circuits are always designed inseparable of certain production technology and equipment at certain factory. Devices or circuits, produced in this factory will not work in real production. For many decades prototyping in microelectronics is done by simulation.